# How to pass a variable from inner class to another class

Tags: java, android

I am very new in Android studio and Java, I tried to convert a variable sensor0 to double by using `CO = new Double(sensor0).doubleValue();` , and I would like to pass the variable to another class to use it. But I cannot use the variable of sensor0 in another class. The value of the variable is always 0.

```
public class bt extends Activity {
public String sensor0, sensor1;
public double CO;

Button btnOn, btnOff, btnNext;
TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, sensorView0, sensorView1, sensorView2, sensorView3;
Handler bluetoothIn;

final int handlerState = 0;                      //used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;


// SPP UUID service - this should work for most devices
private static final UUID ID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// String for MAC address
private static String address;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bt);

    //Link the buttons and textViews to respective views
    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
    txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
    sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView0);
    sensorView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView1);
    sensorView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView2);
    sensorView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorView3);


    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                    txtString.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);
                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                          //get length of data received
                    txtStringLength.setText("String Length = " + String.valueOf(dataLength));

                    if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                    {
                        sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, 4);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                        sensor1 = recDataString.substring(5, 8);            //same again...
                        //String sensor2 = recDataString.substring(11, 15);
                        //String sensor3 = recDataString.substring(16, 20);

                        sensorView0.setText(" CO2 Value = " + sensor0 + "");    //update the textviews with sensor values
                        sensorView1.setText(" CO Value = " + sensor1 + "");
                       // sensorView2.setText(" Sensor 2 Voltage = " + sensor2 + "V");
                       // sensorView3.setText(" Sensor 3 Voltage = " + sensor3 + "V");
                    }
                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                    // strIncom =" ";
                    dataInPrint = " ";
                    CO = new Double(sensor0).doubleValue();

                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you reduce your code to a minimal example? there's currently a lot of code to see through just to find where variables `CO` or `sensor0` are used outside of the class

Comment: Yes sir, I removed some of the code. The sensor0 is inside the `public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)`

Comment: @Kaddath *"reduce your code to a minimal example"* Great idea. But I like to be much (*much*) more specific (with less typing). On that note: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewThompson you're right, i should take this habit for new contributors, as well as the tour when i see no rep points..

Answer (score 0):

you need to allow access to this variable.
the bast way to do this is to define a getter for this variable.

1. create a variable in the class and once your method runs populate the field
2. create a "public" method called getC0() which will return your value.
3. in the class you need this after you create an instance of your class and the logic that populates the variable runs, you can call the method to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `CO = new Double(sensor0).doubleValue();` to `double CO = Double.parseDouble(sensor0);`. Then I get 0 from another class by using the code 
`bt SensorCO = new bt(); 
double COValue = SensorCO.CO;`, 
and below is the code of another class

```
public void setBitmap( Bitmap bitmap ) {
    oldTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()+500)/1000;
    mBitmap = bitmap;

    if (!detector.isOperational()) {
        //Handle contingency
    } else {
        //Log.d("time1", SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+"");
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
        mFaces = detector.detect(frame);
    }

    bt SensorCO = new bt();
    double COValue = SensorCO.CO;

    newTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()+500)/1000;
    timeDifference = (newTime - oldTime);
    accumulate = (accumulate + timeDifference);
    CameraActivity.showScore(blinkCount, accumulate, COValue);


    if(isEyeBlinked()){
        accumulate = 0;
        Log.d("isEyeBlinked","eye blink is observed");
        blinkCount++;

    }
    if(accumulate > 6){
        playSound playSound1 = new playSound();
        playSound1.play(accumulate);

        }


    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

make sure that sensor0 have the right value and then
replace

```
CO = new Double(sensor0).doubleValue();
```

with

```
double CO = Double.parseDouble(sensor0);
```